# Application can't connect to copy of SQL Server database on other computer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have created a C# application that connects to a SQL Server database which I created in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. I need to send my app, my database, and instructions to get them working to someone for assessment.

My application connects perfectly on my computer with the connection string

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ReportsDB;Integrated Security=True
```

However I am testing it on another computer and it will not connect with that same string.

I have installed SQL Server 2014 Express on that computer, and restored the database so it is identical to my main computer.

Any advice on how to make this work, or alternatively make it portable enough to submit?

Comment: Are you using correct db source name,catalog name on the other computer?

Comment: Start basic debugging and give us the error message. Basic debugging would include trying to connect from management studio or with sqlcmd to make sure things are working outside of your application.

Comment: Do you have the DataBase created? First try accessing it from SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio

Comment: @VVN Would you be able to give me pointers on how to ensure I am? My experience with sql is rather limited.

Comment: @SamGhatak Database is created,. I can access it, view records, and all functions working through Management Studio

Comment: @TomTom the error I am getting is "error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server"

Comment: Data source? Missing ODBC setup? Not taht you would need it. The connection string is invalid for the native connector and sqlexpress. What you use to connect? Head over to connectionstrings.com and check.

Comment: @TomTom Currently I am installing VS on the second computer to see if I can connect to the database and check what connection string it uses, to compare to the one I am currently using.

Comment: @TomTom I have been trying different strings, how would I modify the connection string to work with SQLExpress? That very well might be my issue. I don't have an understanding of connection string differences between SQL server and SQL express.

Comment: @GraphiteEdge This is totally useless. There is no need for visal studio. What you use for connecting to the database? your connection string seriously does look non standard.

Comment: Then head over to connectionstrings and learn`? They explain all options on all databases. Most important: YOu need to connect to a named instance "\SqlExpress" as Express is not the default instance per default.

Comment: @TomTom I pulled that connections string out of visual studio on my main machine, and changed the computer name to '(local)' in attempt to make it portable. I am connecting with SQLCommand objects in C# using my sql statements and connection string.

Comment: So you basically installed a database not knowing how to connect to it. Over to connectionstrings.com and read up how to connect to a sql express.

Comment: Try using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and see if you can connect.  It comes with SQL Server.  If you can't connect with SSMS then it is a credential issue and not your C# application.  You can only connect if both you local PC and the remote PC are in the same Group in Windows credentials.   Are you in a Corporate Network?  Most corporate networks use Group Policies which determine if two computers can connect.  You can also try to login to the remote computer from the local computer which may give additional info on isolating the issue.

Comment: It may due to the configuration problem in the other computer

Comment: Okay so I finished installing VS Express on the secondary computer, I then connected it to the SQL Server and looked it the connection string. It used this string : "Data Source=COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ESSReports;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

Using that in my application allowed it to work correctly. Now I wonder how to define a string generic enough for other computers.

Comment: Connection string will change according to computers...otherwise you need to host your db in a common computer/server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that I assumed that connection strings were the same (apart from computer name) between **SQLServer** and **SQLExpress** however they are not.

My solution was rather hacky- I found the SQLExpress Connection String using VS on my second computer, replaced the computer name with the **(local)** keyword and then made an option in my application to switch between the default SQLExpress or SQLServer connection string so the user might change it manually. I also included an option to allow them to completely modify the connection string if neither default works. This is far from the most elegant solution, but with my limited understanding, it is passable to get the system working on a new computer.